# .Value property on Range() in VBA

Tags: excel, vba

Some Excel VBA code I've seen does not used the .Value property on the Range object, for example:

```
myX = Range("A1")
```

rather than

```
myX = Range("A1").Value
```

Is this just because the default behavior of the range object is to return the value in the cell? Is there ever a time when I would *not* want to use this property to access the numerical value in a cell?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Value is the default property of Range.  So any code that expects a property and refers to a Range alone, will get Value.

There are other properties that will return a range's "value" such as Value2, Text, and sometimes Formula* which have their specific uses.

Comment: When are the Value2, Text, and Formula properties returned as default value? I looked at the [documentation of Range](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff838238.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) but no mention at all about default properties. Or is this standard VBA behaviour?

Comment: They are Never returned as default.

Comment: So I misunderstood ;-) I'm still wondering if it's not documented that `Value` is implicitly returned...