# Is there a way to Convert an Object to a String with VBA?

Tags: excel, vba

I have a file split into three columns. One column contains datetime values in the following format.

> mm/dd/yyyy, hh:nn:ss AM/PM

It appears the datetime values are objects.

Output Example:

```
 Value                              Type
 "9/28/2020, 12:46:24 PM"           Variant/Object/Range
```

I tried looking for a method to convert these objects into string or date types. I haven't found a method yet. Do you know of a method that could do this in VBA?

I'm working on a macro to help my teacher friends with their work. It would be perfect if all the work could be achieved in Excel VBA.

**Update:**
*Guys, I understand the definition of a date value. The following functions don't apply to this situation: DateValue, TimeValue, and Cdate. The type is a mismatch for all of them.*

*I'm trying to convert my data to date types. I want to use the DateDiff function to determine the total time a student was in a class session between actions.*

*Excel shows the datetime values as a "variant/object/range" type per locals window. The datetime values cannot be converted to long, or string for some reason. It's quite annoying. I could clean it up with C# but my teacher friends want to stay within the Excel VBA requirement to make things easier for them.*

***Update 2:**
Here's the code i wrote... Just posting the datetime portion.*

```
Sub GetAttendanceData()
    Dim filepath As String
    Dim Size As Integer
    Dim i As Integer
    
    filepath = "file.csv"
    Workbooks.Open filepath
    
    Size = WorksheetFunction.CountA(Worksheets(1).Columns(1))
    
    Dim PE As MeetingAttdList
    Set PE = New MeetingAttdList
    
    PE.Initialize_MeetingAttdList (Size - 1)
    
    For i = 2 To Size
        PE.Name(i - 2) = Worksheets(1).Cells(i, 1)
        PE.Action(i - 2) = Worksheets(1).Cells(i, 2)
        PE.DateTime(i - 2) = Worksheets(1).Cells(i, 3)  //Type Mismatch Occurs Here
    Next i

End Sub



'MeetingAttd Class:

Option Explicit

Dim pDateTime() As DateTime
 
Public Sub Initialize_MeetingAttdList(ColSize As Integer)
     ReDim pDateTime(ColSize)
End Sub

'Property - DateTime
Public Property Get DateTime(i As Integer) As Date
    DateTime = pDateTime(i).DateTime
End Property

Public Property Let DateTime(i As Integer, value As Date)
    Set pDateTime(i) = New DateTime
    pDateTime(i).DateTime = value
End Property





' DateTime Class
Option Explicit

Private m_DateTime As Date

Sub Initialize_ClassDateTime()
    m_DateTime = ""
End Sub

Public Property Get DateTime() As Date
    DateTime = m_DateTime
End Property

Public Property Let DateTime(value As Date)
    m_DateTime = value
End Property
'''
```

Comment: `It appears the datetime values are objects.` No No... The `Type` that is mentioned about is for the cell which has that value and not for datetime values. `I tried looking for a method to convert these objects into string or date types.` You can directly use those values as dates or if required, use `DateValue(rng.Value2)`

Comment: Dates are not objects. They are numbers. The date you quote is represented in Excel as 44102.53222222222. From this number you can extract the date or the time and display either one in whichever format you want. So, what's your objective? What do you want to know?

Comment: If you can share what exactly you want to do ith those values then perhaps we can give a direct solution?

Comment: _It appears the datetime values are objects._ no, they are not.   _One column contains datetime values in the following format._  cells like this will be either numeric values formatted as date time (this is how dates should be stored) or strings that only look like dates (this is problematic and should be avoided)

Comment: Please show your code because I think you are doing something like this `Set v = Range("A1")` where `v` is a variant. Then you end up with the situation you described above.

Comment: `Excel shows the datetime values as a "variant/object/range" type per locals window.` Please re-read my 1st comment again.

Comment: If it's just the date you want then perhaps you can use Range("A1").Text that takes the text value from the cell

Comment: Yes, OP needs to use `value` or `text` property explicitly. Check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25588882/value-property-on-range-in-vba)

Comment: I understood what your problem is. I have voted to reopen the question so that I can post an answer

Comment: IMO the problem is that in the first place OP needs to write `PE.DateTime(i - 2) = Worksheets(1).Cells(i, 3).value` instead of `PE.DateTime(i - 2) = Worksheets(1).Cells(i, 3)` and then of course OP needs to make sure he gets a date but that is a different story, or did I miss something?

Comment: @Storax: No it will not work like that. My answer is ready. waiting for people to vote to open the question

Comment: I did not look into the classes very closely so I voted to re-open.

Comment: Ok, I did not really miss anything. OP just did not make sure he got a date like I wrote above which contradicts his writing _Update: Guys, I understand the definition of a date value._ Sorry, but this was not worth re-opening :-(

Answer (score 1):

> It appears the datetime values are objects.

The `Type` that is mentioned about is for the cell which has that value and not for datetime values.

You can reproduce the same error with this simple example.

Paste `9/28/2020, 12:46:24 PM` in cell `A1` of say `Sheet1`

Next run this code

```
Option Explicit

Sub Sample()
    Dim dt As Date
    dt = Sheet1.Range("A1").Value2
    Debug.Print dt
End Sub
```

You will get the same error

[image]

**Solution:**

Add this in the same module where `GetAttendanceData()` is

```
Function ConvertToDateTime(rngValue As String) As Date
    Dim DateSection As String
    Dim TimeSection As String
    
    DateSection = Split(rngValue, ",")(0)
    TimeSection = Split(rngValue, ",")(1)
    
    ConvertToDateTime = DateValue(DateSection) + TimeValue(TimeSection)
End Function
```

See how I am spliting the string into Date and Time and combining them back again?

Next, change

```
PE.DateTime(i - 2) = Worksheets(1).Cells(i, 3)
```

to

```
PE.DateTime(i - 2) = ConvertToDateTime(Worksheets(1).Cells(i, 3).Value2)
```

And your code will not give you this error again.

**Note:**

1. Avoid using `Worksheets(1)` and give the full name or use codename. For example `Sheet1.` or `Sheets("Sheet1").`
2. Do not use reserved words as variable/object names

Change `value As Date` in `MeetingAttdList` to something else. Someting like

```
Public Property Let DateTime(i As Integer, dtValue As Date)
```

Similarly for

```
Public Property Let DateTime(dtValue As Date)
```

Comment: Thank you @siddharth. That was the solution. I've been thinking about it all evening. I didn't realize the comma was the culprit. I really appreciate your help on this. You're a wizard.